# CSS border inside padding

Tags: html, css

I Have a simple css box made with:

```
border: 1px solid #CCC;
```

I'm trying to add some space from the left side of my text to the border.
I tried with `margins` and `padding` but it's always outside the box, while I would like some margin inside.

My text inside the box is always attached to the left side, how can I add some margin/space between the text and the box?

I have the code on: https://jsfiddle.net/z2v27rcq/ if it helps.

Comment: Not sure what you've tried with `padding`, but it will most definitely add spacing inside the border.

Comment: Please paste your code here not on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `padding`, that's inside the border:

```css
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #AAA">

  <p>
    Hey!
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You weren't using padding properly, you just needed to add some padding to the left:

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #AAA">
  
  <p>
   Hey!
  </p>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add one more div and border to outer div and padding to inner div.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid grey">
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
        <!-- Your Stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add padding on the div itself:

```
  div {
     padding-left: 5px;
    }
```

or add padding to all sides of the box like this:

```
div {
 padding: 5px;
}
```